# How to add the check box for each values after the comma in php?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have the following values

> add,view,edit,delete

How to add the checkbox for each value after the comma. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `explode()` function.

```
$val = "add,view,edit,delete";
$valArr = explode(",", $val);
foreach($valArr as $name)
{
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='type[]' value='".$name."'>".$name." ";
}
```